# How to notate a PDF file in Adobe Reader simply by start writing on the keyboard?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

When a PDF file is open in Adobe Reader I would like to note it (add strikethrough, add note, etc.) once I start typing on the keyboard. For example, assume I have a PDF file that contains only one line `the so`,

- if I select the word `so` and then I type `do`, I would like that Adobe `Add Note to Replace Text`; or
- if I select the word `the` and then I press the `back button` on the keyboard, I would like that Adobe `Strikethrough Text`.

Even though I can do this with the mouse, I prefer doing it with the keyboard only. Is this possible?

Comment: Adobe Reader does not allow editing of PDFs. It allows filling out designed forms, and it allows adding notes, but not editing the actual PDF. Please expand your question to clarify what you are actually asking.

Comment: Your keyboard has a "back" button?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It is the button just above the "Enter" button where there is a `\leftarrow` symbol on it.

Comment: Backspace. In text entry it removes text from the right to the left. In navigation (such as a web page), it goes Back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Adobe Reader, this is not an available option.

If you are limited to using the Adobe Reader software and no third-party utilities or alternative readers, there is no available option to enable the behavior you have described.

Comment: Is there any other tools that do it? Like Foxit or something else?

Comment: I am not aware of any applications that allow behavior such that you click and then begin typing to annotate.